# Numerical type with enough precision for implementing a calculator

Tags: c#, .net, types, primitive-types

I am building a WPF calculator application, and while testing it (comparing with the behavior of the Windows built in calculator) i have seen some differences.

Here's a print out from one of my tests:

> Test 'Comparison.Tests.ComparisonTests' failed:
>
> Expected string length 17 but was 16. Strings differ at index 16.
>   Expected: "175641.7874709774"
>     But was:  "175641.787470977"

I am using a *double* for all my calculations and finally displaying them as a string to a TextBox.

What is the reason of this difference? is double not enough for storing the results for the basic operations (Add, Multiply, Subtract, Divide, SQRT, etc).

Comment: You will probably have better luck with [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Double is plenty if you're willing to accept its limitations (15-16 digits of precision).

If you're using Windows Calculator as the gold standard, you should be aware that it does not use Double internally -- it was [rewritten in Windows 95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculator_%28Windows%29) to use an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library. Per [a blog post by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040525-00/?p=39193):

> Today, Calc's internal computations are done with infinite precision for basic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) and 32 digits of precision for advanced operations (square root, transcendental operators).

Most apps don't need more than 15 digits of precision. If yours does, you'll need to find a library that supports arbitrary-precision math.

Comment: Decimal will not be an easy solution in this case?

Comment: Decimal has 28-29 digits of precision, which is more than Double's 15-16, but it's still finite. It might make this particular test case pass, but it wouldn't give your app the infinite precision that Windows Calculator is capable of, so if you're using Windows Calculator as your reference point, you'll have more tests that fail.

Answer (score 1):

Use `decimal` type. It has more precision. [Check this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx?printable=true) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The `Double` type give you about 15 decimal digits worth of precision, so it does look like you're running into that limitation.  `Decimal` uses 128 bits instead of 64 bits like `Double` does, so that will give you more precision over a similar range.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using decimal.

[Why?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691147%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Contrary to the float and double data types, decimal fractional
>   numbers such as 0.1 can be represented exactly in the decimal
>   representation. In the float and double representations, such numbers
>   are often infinite fractions, making those representations more prone
>   to round-off errors.

And a good resource about arithmetic operations: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Double will give you 53 bits of precision (52 bits in a 64-bit value, with an implicit extra bit for most values).

Decimal will give you 96 bits of precision (in a 128-bit value).

That the exponent of the former is in binary and of the later is decimal means that the "round" numbers in double can be more surprising to users than in decimal.

On the other hand, decimal doesn't do well in contexts where you need to represent infinity or not-a-number.

Most likely, decimal will serve much better double. If you need yet more precision, you could roll your own big-decimal by combining `BigInteger` and a number to hold the scale.